# What is an employee's liability?

Tags: united-states, contract-law, liability, tort, employee

Employee E works as part of a development team for company C, which has a contract with customer F. Suppose that F is dissatisfied with the work product that C submits. Under what circumstances would F succeed in suing E (as opposed to C) for the allegedly defective work?

Answer (score 2):

To sue the employee the customer would have to show that the employee was personally involved in negligently causing the work to be defective, on a negligence theory, and the information necessary to establish this claim would be hard to obtain.

In contrast, the company, C, would have strict liability for both breach of warranty (which is a contract theory) and under a tort based (i.e. non-contractually based) product liability theory. The employee would not have liability under either of these theories.

Comment: Would simple negligence be sufficient to pierce corporate veil and sue the employee? Wouldn't it need to rise to gross negligence?

Comment: @Pyrotechnical It isn't piercing the corporate veil (which only allows you to sue owners and officers and directors of the corporation, not mere employees). You can always sue someone in tort for a tort that they personally participated in. In a simpler case, if you are driving a car on company business and get in an accident that is your fault, both the driver-employee and the company both have joint and several liability for the accident. Here, personal participation in causing the defect is equivalent to driving the car. Veil piercing isn't related to level of negligence either.

Comment: @Pyrotechnical Veil piercing typically has as its central element co-mingling of business and personal property and funds in a way that harms a creditor. It overlaps heavily with liability for a fraudulent transfer as assets to harm a creditor.

Comment: I'm not sure the example of driving the car works with regards to this question. The driver and the person they hit didn't have a contract with each other nor with the company. Additionally, isn't there a level of responsibility one has by accepting a driver's license to drive with care and failing to do so opens you up to liability?

Comment: This may come down to us have differing perceptions of the original question. I perceived it as Customer F attempting to sue a Employee E who is a CAD technician because they prepared plans that weren't sufficient for securing a permit despite the fact that the Customer F has a contract with Company C to prepare the plans. Perhaps Employee E did the best they could (but this wasn't good enough), regardless, the fault lies with Company C as the party failing to uphold the contract.

Comment: @Pyrotechnical Certainly there is no contractual liability, but that doesn't mean there is no tort liability. And everyone has a general duty in tort to take reasonable care to precent harm to others and to do your work in a workmanlike manner. If Employee E screws up the CAD in a way that causes the end product to be defective due to negligence on the part of E (e.g. missing a decimal place or selecting the wrong materials) then E is on the hook. E is not on the hook simply due to failure to meet the contract requirement even though E didn't screw up because a contract term was impossible.

Comment: @Pyrotechnical For example, I have a case where a small firm was hired to make a whisky  still that was defective and exploded destroying a building and causing serious personal injuries, due to design errors and fabrication issues. We know who designed it and who was the lead fabricator, because it was such a small firm, and because of correspondence between the buyer and the firm. We were allowed to sue those employees, and not just the firm, as a result.

Comment: WRT a missing decimal place and similar errors, this doesn't seem like it's the sort of thing where you can successfully sue someone. Lawyers are notorious for suing anyone and everyone who touched a project, but then the matter gets to court and opposing council works to get their clients removed from the lawsuit as quickly as possible. Your example of a missed decimal place could be countered with, "Well they worked under a reviewing engineer, why didn't they catch it?" or "Why on earth would the contractor think 100 lbs of concrete is needed when the norm would be 10?"

Comment: @Pyrotechnical The fact that someone else was also negligent doesn't absolve you of liability for negligence. Basically, if you would say "oops, I screwed up" upon examining what happened, it is negligence and you have liability. You might share liability with others who were also negligent, but that doesn't get you off the hook.

Comment: The supposition of 'workmanlike manner' was something that came up during my college classes on engineering law and it was consistently disparaged because it's imprecise. There's a standard of care within certain fields and perfection isn't generally considered an appropriate standard, hence why there's factors of safety in a design. Part of major manufacturing design includes considering what is an acceptable loss of life when making design decisions. "We could add this widget for safety but it'll increase the cost by $2000, and if we don't add it we estimate XX people might die."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151916/discussion-between-pyrotechnical-and-ohwilleke).

Comment: @Pyrotechnical Workman-like manner and "standards" rather than rules are the norm in tort law and routinely applied despite being imprecise. Indeed, part of the point is that they are imprecise and the jury gets to decide on a case by case basis if the acts were blameworthy. "Acceptable losses" is a very tough argument to make in a strict liability product liability case of the firm especially, since a negligence standard doesn't apply. Economically, it may make sense, but legally, if you don't make the $2000 fix and XX people die, the firm that made it has to pay for those deaths.

Comment: The companies often do pay for those deaths, but not the individual employees. This came up recently in an ethics seminar regarding the Ford Pinto. The costs to modify the design of the vehicle was small, but small costs are multiplied by millions when production is large. Ultimately, the failure of the fuel tanks resulted in approximately 27 deaths out of over 2 million vehicles sold per NHTSA. While these deaths are tragic, their number is actually pretty small compared to other vehicle features (or lack thereof) which have resulted in more fatalities.

Comment: With regards to the Pinto, this isn't a slam-dunk case of engineers doing the unethical or wrong thing (the Challenger disaster often is). They made a cost-benefit analysis and for those who were on the short end of that analysis, Ford ending up having to pay, but the engineers themselves were not sued.

Comment: @Pyrotechnical The engineers would have been liable only for negligence and only if you could figure out which engineers were responsible, which in the case of the Ford Motor Company would be hard. Also Ford was good for any damages assessed, so they didn't need additional defendants. You sue employees when you have an easier case against the entities only when the entity doesn't have deep pockets.

Comment: my point is that the engineers may not have been negligent, rather they were applying a standard of care that is appropriate for the industry. Risk-free design is not possible, especially when dealing with mass production. Strict liability may apply, but when you inquire on whether a design was negligent the standard isn't whether the design was free of any risk. This is why there's industry standards for how much rat feces is permissible in food (https://www.cnn.com/2019/10/04/health/insect-rodent-filth-in-food-wellness/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

### Probably only in the event of malpractice by a licensed professional

In general, the situation of Customer F suing Employee E when their contract is with Company C is pretty much not feasible. Customer F has no contract with Employee E, their contract is with Company C, which is a legal entity that they are transacting with when creating the initial contract.

If Customer F is dissatisfied with the work product provided by Company C, then they need to complain and take action against Company C. Company C can then proceed to try to remedy the situation in any fashion they deem acceptable including having Employee E fix the work; having Employee E2 fix the work; hire Subcontractor S to fix the work; or numerous other options.

Assuming Company C does not fix the issue, Customer F could sue pursuant to the terms of the original contract they have.

---

The second issue that impedes the scenario you described is a legal concept called '[corporate veil](https://www.thienel-law.com/blog/2022/7/28/how-to-keep-establish-corporate-veil)'. Attempting to take action against the employees of a company is generally not legally permissible unless the the corporate veil is pierced, which is generally only allowed when a company is proven to have been created for the purpose of shielding bad actors from consequences.

---

All of that said, there are cases where directly suing an employee could occur and that is in the situation of work being performed by licensed professionals. In my personal experience as a professional engineer, were I to put forth a design that failed to meet the standards of care for my profession, I could be personally sued (and so could my company).

This becomes relevant when we see the fallout from civil engineering disasters like the recent [Florida Pedestrian Bridge Collapse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Florida_International_University_pedestrian_bridge_collapse) wherein the Engineer of Record (EoR) failed to properly address multiple issues during the design and construction process resulting in the collapse.

FIGG Bridge Engineers was the company responsible for the design and Denney Pate was the EoR. [Both FIGG and Pate were penalized](https://www.enr.com/articles/49890-judge-rejects-figgs-motion-to-halt-10-year-debarment) by USDOT which barred them from participating in federal contracts for 10 years.

Comment: Not far from the mark, but professional licensure probably isn't relevant.

Comment: Piercing the corporate veil refers to suing _owners_ of a corporation, not _employees._

Comment: @phoog the original question isn't clear as to exactly who Employee E is with regards to a corporate structure. If they're not an owner then I'd defer to the first part of my answer whereby no contract exists between the employee and the customer. If they are an owner then corporate veil does apply.